# Web service exception handling - looking for alternatives to SOAP

Tags: jquery, service, exception

I'm looking for a design pattern to handle exceptions generated by the web service.

I have looked at the SOAP examples and it's not suitable for my project.

I make the calls to the web services through AJAX. If the call fails or business logic isn't met I'd like to pass a custom object to the browser which will contain some information about the exception. The browser will look at the exception information through java script and handle it. Is this a reasonable thing to do or should I be looking for alternatives?

The only thing I have managed to find so far is SOAP.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use HTTP response status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. There is a 4xx-5xx response code range, which is designed to handle error messaging. It handles the http layer, so you must agree on use specific codes for specific types of errors. See http://distilledme.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/http-status-codes-quick-reference/ to see how http error codes can be applied to REST application.

In general, you probably going to use 500 response code a lot, with payload indicating specific application-level error. If you want to use AJAX, you can embed content into JSON object, which will held app-level error information, i.e.:

```
  // normal response
   {'status': 'ok',
    'error': null,
    'response': some_response}

  // error response (with 500 http code)
   { 'status': 'error',
     'error_msg': 'you should enter your name',
     'error': 'UserInputError'}
```

On client-side, you deserialize JSON, check for 'status' element. If it's equal to 'error', take 'error' value and see what specific error it is (value should be agreed on both, server and client side), and if needed, add some description of error in 'error_msg'. If 'error' is null, you take 'response' object and process it further.

If you use some JavaScript framework, take a look how you can add callback functions to handle errorous server responses (other than 2xx) in uniform way in AJAX requester wrappers (for example, in JQuery you can add global handlers to AJAX events, so you set it once, and use everytime: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events)